# Implement openssl standard commands (e.g. pkcs12) in Ansible 2.4

Tags: linux, openssl, ansible-2.x

I need to implement openssl command pkcs12 in Ansible 2.4
The latest Ansible version provides a module called openssl_pkcs12, but how to implement this in Ansible 2.4?
So far, I have tried to put this command in the action of openssl_certificate like this:

```
name: openssl create hostcertificate.key
openssl_certificate:
  action: pkcs12
  attributes: '"-nocerts" "-nodes"'
  src: <path-to-certificate>.p12
  path: <destination-path>.key
  mode: '400'
  state: present
```

But it throws "*Unsupported paramaters for (openssl_certificate) module*" error as this action is not supported by openssl_certificate module. 
How can I implement this for this version?

Moreover, I need to automate the following openssl command, so please review if there are any other mistakes I made in the above Ansible script:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -nodes -out <destination-path>.key -in <path-to-certificate>.p12
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply resolved by using the 'shell' module. I did it by using the following ansible task:

```
- name: openssl create hostcertificate.key
  shell: "openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -nodes -out <destination-path>/hostcertificate.key -in <path-to-key>/hostcertificate.p12"
```